# Element can be clicked by jquery on browser but not in ruby-watir

Tags: jquery, css, ruby, watir

Using jquery on a browser, I can click the element:

```
$("input[name=\"generalConditions\"]").click();
```

But--using ruby-watir--I can't:

```
$browser.element(:css=> 'input[name="generalConditions"]').click
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
</section>

<section id="condGenerales" class="generalConditions pageSectionName" data-pagesection="generalConditions">
<div class="conditions">
<p class="titulo2">Condiciones generales</p>
<fieldset class="condicionesGenerales">
<div class="checkboxB">
<input type="checkbox" name="generalConditions" id="GC">
<label for="GC">
* He revisado los trayectos, itinerario y destinos de la reserva, siendo estos correctos. He le&#237;do y acepto las 
<a href="https://politicaCobros.htm" target="_blank">pol&#237;tica de cobros</a>,                       
<a href="https://privacidad" target="_blank">pol&#237;tica privacidad</a>,                       
<a href="https://poli.htm" target="_blank">condiciones generales</a>                                        
y acepto el pago de <span class="price totalpricecheckout">297,37&nbsp;<small>&#8364;</small></span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="contErrorDatos mt-20" style="display:none">
Para finalizar la reserva, debes aceptar las condiciones generales y de cancelaci&#243;n de esta reserva
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</section>
```

Element exists but is not present.  How can I click on this checkbox?

Comment: Can you create a sample HTML page, with related CSS, that reproduces the issue? Without the exact scenario, it is hard to be sure why Watir believes the element is not present. However, the most common reason these days is that the `input` is hidden and there is some other styled checkbox image displayed instead. In these cases, clicking the `label` element is required - ie try `$browser.label(for: 'GC').click`

Comment: @JustinKo This is very valid information, yes, clicking that label is working me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is element is hidden, So selenium visibility check would not allow you to click the element, So use Javascript click here, it would work.

Write this code

```
b.input(name: 'generalConditions').fire_event :click
```

Or

```
b.input(id: 'GC').fire_event :click
```

Or

```
b.checkbox(name: 'generalConditions').fire_event :click
```

Comment: Thanks !! it worked like a charm , i tried several solutions and this is the only one worked ,, tahnks

Comment: @user2295727 Can you accept my answer? There is a arrow on the left side you need to click, it will become green after you clicked that one.